# Unrecognised Token <

Tags: meteor, d3.js

Started a project in Meteor and added package d3 according to instructions in atmosphere.

Then wanted to try and add the code of this example (rotating globe) in the `<body>` of the hello.html page

```
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 600;

var radius = height / 2 - 5,
    scale = radius,
    velocity = .02;

var projection = d3.geo.orthographic()
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .scale(scale)
    .clipAngle(90);

var canvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection)
    .context(context);

d3.json("world.json", function(error, world) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var land = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land);

  d3.timer(function(elapsed) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    projection.rotate([velocity * elapsed, 0]);
    context.beginPath();
    path(land);
    context.fill();

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(width / 2, height / 2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    context.lineWidth = 2.5;
    context.stroke();
  });
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

</script>
```

I copied the data of the .JSON file and copied it into the public directory. The data has been checked and is valid.

When starting the application, I get this error:
SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<' on line localhost:26.

This means that the application blocks on about the 15th script Meteor has to load.

Anyone has an idea?

PS also specified the utf-8 charset in the script-tags... didn't help

Edit:

This is the full hello.html page

```
<head>
    <title>hello world</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>

      var width = 960,
              height = 600;

      var radius = height / 2 - 5,
              scale = radius,
              velocity = .02;

      var projection = d3.geo.orthographic()
              .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
              .scale(scale)
              .clipAngle(90);

      var canvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas")
              .attr("width", width)
              .attr("height", height);

      var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

      var path = d3.geo.path()
              .projection(projection)
              .context(context);

      d3.json("world.json", function(error, world) {
          if (error) throw error;

          var land = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land);

          d3.timer(function(elapsed) {
              context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

              projection.rotate([velocity * elapsed, 0]);
              context.beginPath();
              path(land);
              context.fill();

              context.beginPath();
              context.arc(width / 2, height / 2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
              context.lineWidth = 2.5;
              context.stroke();
          });
      });

      d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");
  </script>

    {{>hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
        <button>Left</button>
        <button>Right</button>
</template>
```

Comment: The problem is in the `json` file, not here..

Comment: the json is valid. The code also works if I'm running it "as is", id est, not in the Meteor framework

Comment: And this code does not contain token `<` on line 26. Mystery.

Comment: can you share your full hello.html page: here you are only showing the 'good' code, how do you expect one finds an error in it?
It most likely has to do with how you pasted this in the Meteor page

Comment: I just created a new Meteor project with just your file and it works fine... I don't see the graph but the project doesn't crash. Is that the only file you have?

Comment: you can find the content of the json here
`http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/world-110m.json`
Strange that it works without error code at your place. Tried it with an empty world.json here and still got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to load an external file from the local directory.

In Meteor, files are served from the /public directory:

Create a **/public** directory in your Meteor project

Put the `world.json` file in it

and put the d3 repo scripts in the `<head>` section

EDIT:

the full file:

```
<head>
    <title>hello world</title>
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>

      var width = 960,
              height = 600;

      var radius = height / 2 - 5,
              scale = radius,
              velocity = .02;

      var projection = d3.geo.orthographic()
              .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
              .scale(scale)
              .clipAngle(90);

      var canvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas")
              .attr("width", width)
              .attr("height", height);

      var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

      var path = d3.geo.path()
              .projection(projection)
              .context(context);

      d3.json("world.json", function(error, world) {
          if (error) throw error;

          var land = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land);

          d3.timer(function(elapsed) {
              context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

              projection.rotate([velocity * elapsed, 0]);
              context.beginPath();
              path(land);
              context.fill();

              context.beginPath();
              context.arc(width / 2, height / 2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
              context.lineWidth = 2.5;
              context.stroke();
          });
      });

      d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");
  </script>

    {{>hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
        <button>Left</button>
        <button>Right</button>
</template>
```

with world.json from 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/topojson/master/examples/world-50m.json

Comment: Hi MrE.
world.son is in the /public directory and d3 repo scripts in the head section (incorrectly copy/pasted). Tried also with charset="UTF-8". No luck :(

Comment: I got it running perfectly with the json in the /public folder

Comment: just posted the full file I used, from a newly created Meteor project

Comment: world.json is from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/topojson/master/examples/world-50m.json

Comment: if you look at the debug and why you get the error, you'll see that it's Meteor returning an error page, which the code tries to parse as JSON and it fails. So if it still doesn't work for you, try to figure what the error page is about.

Comment: Mr. E, tried with your link to world-50. works perfectly. So, I guess that there must be some issue with the json file I was working with. Strange as it is valid and that it does work out of a meteor framework. Anyway, happy it works with this data stream. Thanks

Comment: just tried the one you linked to and it works for me. Maybe you didn't cut/paste properly

Comment: Hmm, getting this error now
`Origin http://localhost:4000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: yup: you're not allowed to download this data. i am guessing you are trying to use a url from somewhere... you need to download and serve yourself if you have the rights, or the remote server needs to allow your server to download. Lookup CORS online

Comment: OK, but that doesn't explain why you have access and I don't.
All pretty confusing. I got this first unrecognised error when I copy/pasted this json data in local. Now I get this error when trying to access remotely. But it does work with your file.

Comment: I din't, I downloaded the file locally

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of this error in my experience is that the web server is returning a HTML page (usually an error page) instead of a Javascript file as expected. When the browser tries to parse the HTML as JS, it fails on the first `<` sign.

Check the Network tab of the developer tools to see which of your scripts is actually returning a response which is HTML. Then figure out why that request is causing an error (wrong URL, typo, forgot to check that file into source control, etc etc etc).

Comment: Hi Greg, the scripts are all out of the box Meteor and D3.

Comment: @Charles Did you check in developer tools to make sure they are all being returned as JS, not HTML?